# Orthogonality of invariant subspaces for restricted representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two proper subgroups of $G$. Also, let $\rho:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^m$ be an irreducible non-trivial representation of $G$. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^m$ such that $V_1 \cap V_2=0$. Further, $V_1$ is the maximal subspace such that for every element $h_1 \in H_1$ and $v \in V_1$, $\rho(h_1) v = v$. Similarly, $V_2$ is the maximal subspace such that for every element $h_2 \in H_2$ and $v \in V_2$, $\rho(h_2) v = v$.

Is it true that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal to each other (w.r.t the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^m$) ? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: orthogonal with respect to what?

Comment: @Jonas : orthogonal w.r.t. the standard inner product function. 

Comment: What the hell is $\rho:G\to\mathbb C^m\times \mathbb C^m$ supposed to mean? Maybe $\rho:G\to \mathrm{End}\mathbb C^m$ ?

Comment: Anyway, by the definition of $V_1$, an irrep of $G$ occurs in $V_1$ iff it occurs in $\mathbb C^m$ and trivializes $H_1$ (i. e., the group $H_1$ acts trivially in this irrep). Similarly, an irrep of $G$ occurs in $V_2$ iff it occurs in $\mathbb C^m$ and trivializes $H_2$ (i. e., the group $H_2$ acts trivially in this irrep). Thus, no irrep can occur in both $V_1$ and $V_2$ (because then it would trivialize both $H_1$ and $H_2$, and thus occur in $V_1\cap V_2$, contradicting $V_1\cap V_2=0$). Therefore, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal with respect to any $G$-invariant (!) scalar product.

Comment: Of course, they need not be orthogonal with respect to some random (e. g., standard) scalar product (in fact, there is no reason why the standard scalar product here should be better than any randomly chosen one - think of representations of $G$ as some vector spaces, not necessarily $\mathbb C^m$).

Comment: Surely the inner product should be $G$-invariant (this gets rid of the ambiguity, up to scalars, thanks to the irred. of $\rho$).

Comment: Reformulation?: Let $G$ be a finite group, let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be subgroups of $G$ and let $V$ be a complex irrep of $G$ such that $\{v \in V \ | \ H_1 v=v \} \cap \{v \in V \ | \ H_2 v=v \}=\{0\}$.  Is it true that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal wrt a $G$-invariant inner product on $V$?

Comment: (Oops, the $V_1$ and $V_2$ above were the fixed spaces of $H_1$ and $H_2$.)

Comment: By the way, I may be fooling myself but I actually think it was not too hard to figure out what the OP meant, and darij's comment above claiming that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal is not the correct answer to that question.  

Comment: I was talking about the sesquilinear inner product, not the bilinear inner product. But things like this should be cleared up by the OP, in my opinion.

Comment: @darij: I don't understand the distinction: in my answer, either bilinear or sesquilinear will do (b/c the underlying rep'n is real).  The key point seems to be that you are assuming that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are $G$-stable, and I don't understand where you get this assumption from.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot - this does disprove it!

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order $6$ acting on its reflection representation $V_{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}^2$ (as symmetries of an equilateral triangle) and let $V$ be the complexification of this representation.  Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be the subgroups of order $2$ generated by distinct reflections.  Then the fix spaces of $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not orthogonal wrt the $G$-inv. inner product, but they intersect trivially.

Comment: Yes, this disproves it for bilinear inner products.

Comment: ...and for sesquilinear (linear in first variable, conjugate linear in the 2nd) ones.